# Why my chunk files doesn't exist in "./static/js" during build? How can I change only chunk files path in webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build, csp-html-webpack-plugin

I want to build my project but my chunk files are generated in wrong path. I have tried publicPath, chunkFilename.. but they doesn't work. I want to move chunk files in ./build/static/js path.
**my config-overrides.js file is here**

```
const path = require('path');
const { override } = require('customize-cra');
const cspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require("csp-html-webpack-plugin");
const cspConfigPolicy = {
    'default-src': "'self'",
    'script-src': ["'self'", "*.googleapis.com", "*.googletagmanager.com", "*.google-analytics.com", "*.facebook.net"],
   'font-src': ["'self'", "https://fonts.gstatic.com "],
    'frame-src ': ["'self'", "*.youtube.com "],
}
    ;

function addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin(config) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        config.plugins.push(new cspHtmlWebpackPlugin(cspConfigPolicy));
    }

    return config;
}

const publicPathPlugin = (config, env) => {
    config.output = {
        filename: `[name].[hash:2].js`,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
      //publicPath: '/',
      //chunkFilename: `[name].[hash:2].js`,
    }
    return config
}

module.exports = {
    webpack: override(addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin, publicPathPlugin),
};
```

that's doesn't generate js folder in static folder for chunk files. Chunk files are generating direct in build folder.
**and my output files is here**

[image]
[image]

**but my want like this**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find solution. I just changed chunkFilename and it worked.

```
chunkFilename: `static/js/[name].[hash:2].js`
```